# angular 5 template forms detect change of form validity status

Tags: angular, forms, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

are [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#observe-control-changes) the way to go in order to have a component that can listen for changes in the validity status of the form it contains and execute some compoment's methods?

It is easy to disable the submit button in the template using templateRef like `[disabled]="#myForm.invalid"`, but this does not involve the component's logic.

Looking at [template forms' doc](https://angular.io/guide/forms) I did not find a way

Answer (score 92, accepted):

If you want to get only the `status` and not the `value` you can use `statusChanges`:

```
export class Component {

    @ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

    this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(
        result => console.log(result)
    );
}
```

If you even want data changes, you can subscribe to the `valueChanges` of the `form` and check the status of the form using `this.myForm.status`:

```
export class Component {

    @ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(
        result => console.log(this.myForm.status)
    );
}
```

Possible values of status are: **VALID**, **INVALID**, **PENDING**, or **DISABLED.**

[Here is the reference for the same](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#observe-control-changes)

Comment: Don't know who did the downvote... Since myForm would be an instance of AbstractControl, it is even better to subscribe to form.statusChanges which returns an observable of VALID, INVALID, PENDING or DISABLED.

I'm actually a bit worried about PENDING as I don't know its meaning...

Comment: Pending is when the Angular is in middle of a validation check, when it starts validating and going through all the checks, the status starts `pending` and it eventually change to either `Valid` or `Invalid`

Comment: and If you dont need the data changes, you can use `statusChanges`

Comment: So I can just ignore PENDING and wait for a new stats value to be emitted. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Thank you @Sravan for the valuable answer. It worked. But is there any way we can delay the change detection like for 5 seconds? Actually I am calling api for saving data and change detection is sending too many requests. Please put some light on it.

Comment: @AdnanSheikh you can use `debounceTime` to delay the change detection. Example: `this.myForm.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(5000)).subscribe(result => console.log('Form changes', result));`.

Answer (score 11):

You can do something like this do detect a validity change and execute a method based on whether the form is `VALID` or `INVALID`.

```
this.myForm.statusChanges
  .subscribe(val => this.onFormValidation(val));

onFormValidation(validity: string) {
  switch (validity) {
    case "VALID":
      // do 'form valid' action
      break;
    case "INVALID":
      // do 'form invalid' action
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This could be minimised to a ternary operator:
`validity === "VALID" ? methodOne() : methodTwo()` *however* I warn to please be careful and not use this approach in large files - it can be weird syntax to consider in large files.

Answer (score 2):

I could be late to the party but @Viewchild('anything') may lead to this error

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'statusChanges')
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'valueChanges')
```

You can simply subscribe to the form. Code Example:

```
form:FormGroup;

ngOnInit(){
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((result: any) =>
      console.log('values changes here') );}
```

Comment: this worked for me because @ViewChild gave errors reading statusChanges and valueChanges

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to the whole form changes and implement your logic there.

```
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm;

this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(data => console.log('Form changes', data));
```