# Angular 2 template driven forms and statusChanges

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I wonder if it possibile to access `statusChanges` in Angular 2 Template driven forms.

I tried the approach offered by this answer, but it doesn't work.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49666202/6920871

Should I refactor the form as Reactive or can I use another approach to emit an event when form validation status changes?

__

Current approach that does not work:

In component TS

```
export class FormComponent implements OnInit {

    [...]

    @ViewChild('myForm', { static: false }) myForm;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let c = this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(() => {
            console.log(this.myForm.status, "Is form dirty yet: " + this.myForm.dirty);
        });
    }
```

in component template

```
<form #myForm>
[...]
</form>
```

I get a `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at FormComponent.ngAfterViewInit (form.component.ts:27)`

(also `this.myForm` is defined, but no property `statusChanges`)

Comment: If you want more programmatic control over your form, I'd strongly suggest switching to reactive forms.

Comment: @xdecdec it's a huge refactor of a form other people are working on and I wonder if I can avoid the refactor.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're getting the reference to the element named myForm, instead of getting a reference to the NgForm directive hosted by this element.

Change `'myForm'` to `NgForm`, or use the `read: NgForm` option.

```
  @ViewChild('myForm', { read: NgForm, static: false })
  myForm: NgForm;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myForm.statusChanges.subscribe(e => console.log('status changed: ' + e));
  }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mbgudy)

Also note that your component should implement `AfterViewInit`.

Comment: Thank you very much, was struggling with this.